# jQuery Ajax Array serializes incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a weird one, although it should be very simple.

The code:

```
var recipients = [];
recipients.push(uuid1);
recipients.push(uuid2);

$.ajax({ 
    url: '/api-url/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'recipient': recipients, 'message': message, 'subject': subject},
    dataType: 'json'
}) ...
```

This is caught in the Chrome Network inspector:

```
recipient[]:8b99fa41-0f8f-4882-b14f-dc258a765b15
recipient[]:add61999-9baa-4096-a92f-fbb144a4a981
subject:test
message:testtest
```

This arrives to the server:

```
{u'recipient[]': [u'8b99fa41-0f8f-4882-b14f-dc258a765b15', u'add61999-9baa-4096-a92f-fbb144a4a981'], u'message': [u'testtest'], u'subject': [u'test']}
```

As you can see, we have a 'recipient' in the ajax call, two instances of 'recipient[]' in network inspector and one 'recipient[]' on the server with correct data, but wrong param name.

Any ideas how is that '[]' in 'recipient[]' getting there?

Comment: It's standard to add `[]` to the param if the param represents an array. Some server-side languages/plugins etc remove this, others don't. you appear to be working with one that doesn't. You can try messing with jQuery's `traditional` flag, build the param string yourself, or you can work with what you've got.

Answer (score 2):

This is what JQuery does to your data object:

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
>   (described below).

To send it as JSON you need to convert it to JSON string:

```
...
type: 'POST', 
data: JSON.stringify({'recipient': recipients, 'message': message, 'subject': subject}),
```

Comment: That did help, but I got a bad request until I added: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" and dataType: "json" to the ajax setup.

Comment: @dnmh yes, better to be explicit. Without the contentType header your server seems to expect url-encoded parameters.